# Fieldset adjustment

Tags: html, checkbox, radio-button, fieldset

I want to create on my website 2 fields (abreast), but there is something wrong... It shows me two fields in itself and last words didn't show me. Please help

[Sorry for my English]

My HTML:

```
<table rows="1" cols="2">
  <tr>
      <td valign="top">
          <fieldset>
              <legend><font size="+1">Tovar</font></legend>
               <br>
               <input type="checkbox" name="bateria"> Použitá jednorazová baterka
               <br>
               <input type="checkbox" name="rozok"> Celozrnný rožok
               <br>
               <input type="checkbox" name="auto> Neviditeľné auto
        </fieldset>
    <td valign="top" width="50%">
      <fieldset>
        <legend><font size="+1"> Spôsob platby </font></legend>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="platba"> Master Card
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

missing a double quote in the name attribute in the third checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="auto>
```

Should be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="auto">
```

Full code:

```
<table rows="1" cols="2">
  <tr>
      <td valign="top">
          <fieldset>
              <legend><font size="+1">Tovar</font></legend>
               <br>
               <input type="checkbox" name="bateria"> Použitá jednorazová baterka
               <br>
               <input type="checkbox" name="rozok"> Celozrnný rožok
               <br>
               <input type="checkbox" name="auto"> Neviditeľné auto
        </fieldset>
     </td> <!-- <== Missing </td> here and you are missing a double quote in the name attribute in the third checkbox  -->
     <td valign="top" width="50%">
      <fieldset>
        <legend><font size="+1"> Spôsob platby </font></legend>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="platba"> Master Card
        ...
```

Comment: The end tag for td elements is optional. (And your change is very non-obvious since you hide it in a comment in the middle of a huge block of code).

Comment: @Quentin How did you figure out the comment in the middle of this huge block?

Comment: I stared at it long enough and corrected myself half way through typing a comment along the lines of "Why would indenting the last few lines help?"

Comment: Well it was to give and show the context of the error yes `</td>` is optional but helps in overall debugging (in a sense).